# How to add types for third-party components in vue SFC template?

Tags: node.js, typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vue-composition-api

I am using volar+vue2+ts+composiiton api. In SFC templates, for custom components, volar is able to perform type checks and give the following message when some errors encountered. It benefits me a lot.

[image]

I wonder if the type check is also applicable on components from third-party packages such as `element-ui`. When hovering over tags like `el-*`(components from `element-ui`), volar says it has the type of `any` and type check is not available. For `jsx` components, one can add types to the `IntrinsicElements` in `shims-tsx.d.ts`. But `IntrinsicElements` doesn't work for SFC templates. Is it possible to add types for third-party components?

```js
import Vue, { VNode } from 'vue';


declare global {
  namespace JSX {
    interface Element extends VNode {}
    interface ElementClass extends Vue {}
    interface IntrinsicElements {
      // JSX can add types here
      'el-button': any;
      [elem: string]: any;
    }
  }
}
```

---

As @Finn said, element-ui has added types. Unfortunately, even though `El*` classes are imported and registered via vue's `components` option, volar seems to be unable to do type checks. Here `ElHeader` is expected to have a prop named `height` of type string. But it is assigned a number without any error message

[image]

The following code snippet comes from the source of element-ui

```js
export declare class ElHeader extends ElementUIComponent {
  /** Height of the header */
  height: string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Element-ui for vue2 has added components type declare in [package](https://npm.runkit.com/element-ui/types/input.d.ts),

so volar's type checks follows the package's types declaration.

Comment: volar can't directly leverage those types declaration. I am still wondering if there exists any way to use these types combined with jsx-like `IntrinsicElements` tricks :-)